# Excel: Status based on values in another range

Tags: excel

I have a Status column in a sheet I am working with, and I need to have an overall progress status based on status within that status column. For example:

Scenario 1:

**Status**
Not Started
Not Started
Not Started

Overall Progress Status: (should be) Not Started

2:

**Status**
In Progress
Not Started
Not Started

Overall Progress Status: (should be) In Progress

3:

**Status**
Pass
Pass
Pass

Overall Progress Status: (should be) Pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to get what you want.

For example, you could put IF statements together with what's known as 'nesting':

```
=IF(AND(A2="Not started",A3="Not started",A4="Not started"),"Not started",IF(AND(A2="Pass",A3="Pass",A4="Pass"),"Pass","In progress"))
```

This will return 'Not started' if they are all 'Not started', 'Pass' if they are all 'Pass' and will default to 'In progress" otherwise.

You could also count up how many of each phrase you have got and construct your IFs based on that.

Comment: Here is a slight improvement to your solution: `=IF(COUNTIF(A2:A4,"Not started")=COUNTA(A2:A4),"Not started",IF(COUNTIF(A2:A4,"pass")=COUNTA(A2:A4),"pass","In progress"))`. I'd consider it an improvement as the range can be easily altered to include more cells. But that's just me. Other that that *(+1)* from my side.